# Rails 3 query between two tables

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to find all `learners` associated with a particular `event`. I am calling those folks *registrants*. Right now here is what I have in my controller:

```
@registrants = EventConnection.where(event_id: @event.id, connectiontype: 6)
```

...and in my view I am doing:

```
<% @registrants.each do |r| %>
   <%= Learner.find(r.learner.id).name %>
<% end %>
```

I would like the query from my controller to return a set of learners so I could just do something like:

```
<% @registrants.each do |r| %>
   <%= r.name %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance!

## Edit

Learner :has_many event_connections

EventConnection belongs_to :learner

Comment: Mention your associations between tables

Comment: event has_many learners?

Comment: @user123 correct `has_many :learners, through: :event_connections`

Answer (score 0):

Write this :

```
@registrants = EventConnection.include(:learner)
               .where(event_id: @event.id, connectiontype: 6)
```

Now, you can do:

```
<% @registrants.each do |r| %>
   <%= r.learner.name %>
<% end %>
```

Read this concept of [Eager Loading Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

Answer (score 0):

update controller code as

```
@registrants = EventConnection.where(event_id: @event.id, connectiontype: 6).includes(:learners)
```

view code to list all associated learners to each registrant is

```
<% @registrants.each do |r| %>
   <% r.learners.each do |l|
     <%= l.name %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Controller:

```
@registrants = EventConnection.where(event_id: @event.id, :connection_type => 6).joins(:learner).select(:name)
```

At View:

```
<% @registrants.each do |r| %>
   <%= r.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: With this one getting the error "no implicit conversion of Symbol into String"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rails delegates](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2010/07/24/the-law-of-demeter/) to access associate columns with single (.)

for this add in EventConnection.rb

```
belongs_to :learner 
delegate :name, :to => :learner , :prefix => true
```

so that you can use in view as

```
<% @registrants.each do |r| %>
   <%= r.learner_name %>
<% end %>
```

even if registrants dont have learner, it will handle error for nil class

For optimizing query i.e. fetch learner with `event_connections` you can use [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) as

```
@registrants = EventConnection.include(:learner)
               .where(event_id: @event.id, connectiontype: 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Event

has_many :event_connections
has_many :learners, through: :event_connections
```

Learner

```
has_many :event_connections
has_many :events, through: :event_connections
```

EventConnection

```
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :learner
```

Then your query will become:

```
@registrants = EventConnection.includes(:event => :learners).where(event_id: @event.id, connectiontype: 6)
```